# How to package native libraries eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, native, lwjgl

I'm trying to export a slick2d project from eclipse and I have to use the lwjgl libary including its natives, which I'm having a problem with. I've tried exporting the project and it does not put the natives into the .jar, and i tried programming the import into the program but it says it can't find something called libawt.so, I think is what it's called, it works fine when i run it in eclipse if I set lwjgl.jar's native library but not when I export it. does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5stQZqOAM70) video, it has some nice instructions on how to export your application. Basically, you just use JarSplice (download it [here](http://ninjacave.com/resources/jarsplice/jarsplice-0.40.jar)), and run. JarSplice also lets you export your application as a OSX app bundle, and a .exe file.